# What is the locus of $u|z-P| = v|z-Q|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, plane-geometry, locus

What is the locus of $u|z-P| = v|z-Q|$
where $u \ge 0, v \ge 0,
u+v > 0$?

This is a generalization of
[Identify the plane defined by $|z-2i| = 2|z+3|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279971/identify-the-plane-defined-by-z-2i-2z3).

My result,
after some annoyingly complex algebra
is this:

Let $P=a+bi$
and
$Q = c+di$.

If $u=v$
the locus is the
line
$$0
=-2x(a-c)
-2y(b-d)
+(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)
$$
which is the 
perpendicular bisector of
the line joining
$P$ and $Q$.

If
$u \ne v$
the locus is the circle
with center
$\left(\dfrac{au^2-cv^2}{u^2-v^2},
\dfrac{bu^2-dv^2}{u^2-v^2}\right)
$
and radius
$\dfrac{uv}{u^2-v^2}\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}
$.

My questions are
is this correct
(especially the second part)
and
is there a simpler way
(probably using vectors)
to derive these?

I wouldn't be surprised if this is
already here, somewhere.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218323/291201) for the complete derivation, with a slightly different notation (the $k$ there is equivalent to your $v/u\,$). The locus is indeed either the perpendicular bisector of the segment $PQ\,$ for $u=v\,$, or a circle of Apollonius having as diameter the two points which divide the segment $PQ$ in ratio $v : u \ne 1$ internally and externally.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of doing it like that answer, but I wanted to have my question be symmetric in the two sides.