# Find the locus of $|z-2i|=3|z+3|$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I got as far as

$$|z-2i|=3|z+3| \Leftrightarrow \\ 
(\ldots) \Leftrightarrow \\
x^2-y^2+4y-4=9x^2+54x+81-9y^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
x^2-9x^2-y^2+9y^2+4y-4-54x-81=0\Leftrightarrow \\
-8x^2+8y^2+4y-85-54x=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
8y^2+4y-8x^2-54x-85=0\Leftrightarrow \\
y^2+\frac{1}{2}y-x^2-\frac{27}{4}x=\frac{85}{8}$$

Then I tried to complete the square:

$$y^2+\frac{1}{2}y = 0\Leftrightarrow (y+\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{1}{16}$$

$$-x^2-\frac{27}{4}x=0 \Leftrightarrow -(x+\frac{27}{8})^2+\frac{729}{64} = 0 \Leftrightarrow (x+\frac{27}{8})^2-\frac{729}{64} = 0$$

And so the equation becomes:

$$(y+\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{1}{16}+(x+\frac{27}{8})^2-\frac{729}{64}=\frac{85}{8} \Leftrightarrow \\
(y+\frac{1}{4})^2+(x+\frac{27}{8})^2=\frac{85}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{729}{64} $$

According to my book the center is $-\frac{27}{8}-\frac{1}{4}i$ which I got right but the radius is $\frac{\sqrt{117}}{8}$.

What went wrong?

Comment: I think I've seen this question

Comment: $$|a+ib| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{(a+bi)(a-bi)}. \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$$ It looks as if you used $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}. \qquad$

Comment: @YujieZha Yeah I posted it before, made some progress, deleted it and now I'm stuck again.

Comment: Duplicate of [Identify the plane defined by $|z-2i| = 2|z+3|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279971/identify-the-plane-defined-by-z-2i-2z3). @YujieZha This was posted *twice* before, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279971/identify-the-plane-defined-by-z-2i-2z3) and again [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288545/show-that-the-locus-of-z-2i-3z3-is-a-circumference-of-center-27-8-i-4) yesterday. The latter one was closed as duplicte, then the OP deleted it and reposted the same question now. Somebody is gaming the system (-1).

Comment: Why accept a post which merely re-explains a part of a question you yourself previously posted? Indeed something is fishy here...

Comment: @dxiv thanks for making this explicit, it is really helpful for the community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have $$|x+iy-2i|=3|x+3+iy|$$ from here we get
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}=3\sqrt{(x+3)^2+y^2}$$
can you finish now?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is way up at the top. You wrote $x^2 - y^2 + 4y-4$, when it should have been  $x^2 + y^2 - 4y+4$. Similarly, $9x^2 - 9y^2 + 54 x + 81$ should have been $9x^2 + 9y^2 + 54 x + 81$.