# Prove that $|z-10|=3|z-2$| is the equation of a circle with radius $3$ and center $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove that $|z-10|=3|z-2$| is the equation of a circle with radius $3$ and center $1$.

I tried the following solution, with no result:

Considering $z=x+yi$,

$$|x+yi-10|=3|x+yi-2|$$

$$|(x-10)+yi|=3|(x-2)+yi|$$

$$\sqrt{(x-10)^2+y^2}=3\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}$$

power of $2$:

$$(x-10)^2+y^2=9((x-2)^2+y^2)$$

after simplification, we will have:

$$8x^2+8y^2-16x-64=0$$

or: $$x^2+y^2-2x-8=0$$

I tried $z=x-yi$, as well. But there is no way I can come up with the intended result, that is, radius of $3$ and center of $1$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The locus of points in the plane with constant ratio $\,\left|\dfrac{z-10}{z-2}\right| = 3\,$ between the distances to the two fixed points $\,10, 2\,$ is a [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius.27_definition_of_a_circle) having as diameter the points that divide the segment between $\,10\,$ and $\,2\,$ in ratio $\,3:1\,$ internally and respectively externally. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218323/291201) for the general proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost at end of your exercise. Just notice that 
$$0=x^2+y^2-2x-8=(x-1)^2+y^2-9=|z-1|^2-3^2\Leftrightarrow |z-1|=3$$
where $z=x+iy$.