# Find the Cartesian equation of the locus described by $|z+2-7i| = 2|z-10+2i|$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, locus

> Find the Cartesian equation of the locus described by $|z+2-7i| =
>  2|z-10+2i|$ Write your answer in the form $(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2=k$.

This was a question from my end of year exams just gone and I'm unsure as to where I have gone wrong :(. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate that.

Here was my working:

Let $z = x+iy$
$|z|$ = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$$|z+2-7i| = 2|z-10+2i| \\
\implies |(x+iy)+2-7i| = 2|(x+iy)-10+2i| \\  
\implies |(x+2)(y-7y)i| = 2|(x-10)+(y+2)i| \\ 
\implies \sqrt{(x+2)^2+(y-7)^2i^2} = 2\sqrt{(x-10)^2+(y+2)^2i^2}  \\
\implies (x+2)^2-((y-7^2) = 2((x-10)^2-(y+2)^2)$$

$$(x^2+4x+4)-(y^2-14y+49) = 2((x^2-20x+100)-(y^2+2y+4)) \\
\implies x^2+4x+4-y^2+14y-49 = 2x^2-40x+200-2y^2-4y-8 \\
\implies -237 = x^2-44x-y^2-18y\\
\implies x^2-44x-y^2-18 = -237$$

Comment: See basic MathJax formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Then see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218133/proving-the-apollonian-circle-formula/2218323#2218323).

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for tips on how tou make your postings readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $|z+a+bi|=2|z+c+di|$. Squaring gives
$$(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2=4(x+c)^2+4(y+d)^2$$
that is
$$3(x^2+y^2)+(8c-2a)x+(8d-2b)y+4c^2+4d^2-a^2-b^2=0.$$
In general this is a circle. Now put in your values of $a,\ldots,d$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that in general the equation

$$|z+a+bi|=k|z+c+di|\iff\frac{|z+a+bi|}{|z+c+di|}=\frac{d_1}{d_2}=k$$

describes a circle known as [**Circle of Apollonius**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).

Thus as an alternative you could find C and D by the given condition and then the center $O$ and radius $R$ of the circle

$$O=\frac{C+D}{2} \quad R=OD=OC$$

[image]

Comment: As fully proved at the link posted in my comment under the original question. You should elaborate some more in order to make this into a proper answer.

Comment: @dxiv my intent is to give a general interpretation of the given equation, for the solution of this particular case the OP receveid already many good hints and ways to solve, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not an answer as written now, maybe a comment at best.

Comment: @dxiv it is more an hint ang gives an idea to solve the problem by a different approach, finding C and D and the the center for example, is up to the OP decide if try this way or not

Comment: Your latest edit is a step forward towards making it into an answer.

Comment: Gimusi.Your contribution to this problem is putting it in a wider context , Appolonius, and illustrating it very nicely. That is fine with me:)))

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks a lot for the appreciation Peter. Yes I think that this is a must have reference for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Consider z= (x+iy),Now put the value of Z in the given question. 
after applying rules of modulus 
we get `x^2+Y^2-28x+10y+121=0
Now we can arrange in square form like
(x-14)^2+(y+5)^2=45

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).